# Updating Columns in SQL Server using triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I have a table that is updated by an external application. I have the following Columns:

- OldReading
- OldReadDate
- MeterReading
- ReadDate
- ConfirmReading

MeterReading, ReadDate and ConfirmReading are updated by the application. ConfirmReading is only updated if MeterReading is outside of an acceptable range.

I need the following to happen:

1) When MeterReading and ReadDate is updated in the table, OldReading and OldReadDate should be updated with those values in the same table.

2) However, if ConfirmReading is also updated; OldReading should be updated with this value instead.

3) After OldReading and OldReadDate have been updated in the above ways, the MeterReading, ConfirmReading and ReadDate should be set to 0, 0, NULL respectively.

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Set_Old_Streetlight_Readings_to_New] ON [dbo].[M_FRSCHH_STRLGHT_METER]

AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF UPDATE(MeterReading) AND UPDATE(ConfirmReading)

        BEGIN

            UPDATE [dbo].[M_FRSCHH_STRLGHT_METER]

                SET [OldReading] = [ConfirmReading], [OldReadDate] = [ReadDate]
                WHERE ConfirmReading != 0
        END

ELSE

    IF UPDATE(MeterReading)

        BEGIN

            UPDATE [dbo].[M_FRSCHH_STRLGHT_METER]

                SET OldReading = MeterReading, OldReadDate = ReadDate
                WHERE ConfirmReading = 0

        END

    IF UPDATE(OldReading)
        BEGIN

            UPDATE [dbo].[M_FRSCHH_STRLGHT_METER]

            SET MeterReading = 0, ConfirmReading = 0, ReadDate = NULL, ReadingPhoto = NULL, Reading_Flag = Null
            WHERE MeterReading != 0
    END
END
```

It sort of works when both MeterReading and Confirm Reading updates, but not if only MeterReading Updates.

TIA,

Jason

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag, because the code looks like SQL Server.

Comment: First, the trigger updates all the rows (taking WHERE into account), not only  updated rows, is it correct ?

Comment: Next, `SET OldReading =...     IF UPDATE(OldReading)` may trigger recursion, if it's allowed on DB. Is it correct?

Comment: That is correct Serg

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this code does anything useful at all.  It is not using the `inserted` or `deleted` "tables".  I would expect something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Set_Old_Streetlight_Readings_to_New]
    ON [dbo].[M_FRSCHH_STRLGHT_METER]
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF UPDATE(MeterReading) AND UPDATE(ConfirmReading)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[M_FRSCHH_STRLGHT_METER]
            SET [OldReading] = [ConfirmReading],
                [OldReadDate] = [ReadDate]
            FROM [dbo].[M_FRSCHH_STRLGHT_METER] lm JOIN
                 inserted i
                 ON lm.?? = i.??
            WHERE i.ConfirmReading = 0
        END;
    END;
    . . . 
END;
```

I don't know what column is used to match the `inserted` to the data in the row.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for your comment. So I get what you say, but the table is not deleted or inserted, it is constantly updated. Where both MeterReading and ConfirmReading are updated, the script works perfectly. It just fails when only MeterReading is updated. I'm fairly new to SQL Server, so be gentle.

Comment: @JasonPretorius . . . Your code is updating *all* the rows in `M_FRSCHH_STRLGHT_METER`.  That seems undesirable to me.

Comment: I agree, I have changed it to resemble your recommend code, but having some issue with ambiquity now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `INSTEAD OF` trigger, it fits your requirement more naturally. Second, `UPDATE()` will return true even if the columns are updated with same values, from your narrative I presume this is not what you wanted.

Here's a sample trigger:

```
create trigger Set_Old_Streetlight_Readings_to_New
on dbo.M_FRSCHH_STRLGHT_METER
instead of update
as
begin
set nocount on

;with x as (
    select 
        i.OldReading,
        i.OldReadDate,
        i.MeterReading,
        i.ReadDate,
        i.ConfirmReading,
        d.OldReading d_OldReading,
        d.OldReadDate d_OldReadDate,
        d.MeterReading d_MeterReading,
        d.ReadDate d_ReadDate,
        d.ConfirmReading d_ConfirmReading
    from inserted i
    join M_FRSCHH_STRLGHT_METER d on i.<pk> = d.<pk>
        and i.MeterReading <> d.MeterReading and i.ReadDate <> d.ReadDate
)
update x
set
    d_OldReading = case when OldReading <> d_OldReading then ConfirmReading else MeterReading end,
    d_OldReadDate = ReadDate,
    d_MeterReading = 0,
    d_ConfirmReading = 0,
    d_ReadDate = null

END
```

Comment: I get "Invalid Column errors" when I execute using this code. I will use it as a basis from which to work. Thank you